# Lost of scope with async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, asynchronous, express

I new at javascript so this might be something trivial. I am trying to run a set of functions in series according to waterfall method of async module for Node JS/Restify. The main advantage of this method is that it is possible to pass the "results" of the current callback to the next and so on having the possibility to break the "waterfall" and run the next middleware.

As described in the documentation its arguments are an array of functions and a last middleware.

So I setup my functions according to the code below and call

```
var fn1 = function(callback){
    console.log(req.params.user_id);
    callback(null, req.params.user_id);
};

var fn2 = function(user_id, callback){
    console.log(user_id);
    callback();
}

server.get('/:user_id',
    function(req, res, next){
        async.waterfall([fn1, fn2],
        function(err, result){
            next();
        })
    },
    ...(next middleware)
)
```

And I am not getting the expected results, as the req object is not defined. However when doing this:

```
 server.get('/:user_id',
      function(req, res, next){
          async.waterfall([
              function(callback){
                   console.log(req.params.user_id);
                   callback(null, req.params.user_id);
              },
              function(user_id, callback){
                   console.log(user_id);
                   callback();
              }
          ],
          function(err, result){next()});
      },
      ...(next middleware)
  )
```

I get the results expected and the req object is well defined in the scope of function 1 (fn1).

So I think I am missing something quite basic but don't no where to start..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closures work in the scope that the functions are created in. Not the scope they are executed in. For example, the following should work:

```
server.get('/:user_id', function(req, res, next) {
  var fn1 = function(callback){
      console.log(req.params.user_id);
      callback(null, req.params.user_id);
  };

  var fn2 = function(user_id, callback){
      console.log(user_id);
      callback();
  }

  async.waterfall([fn1, fn2],
    function(err, result){
      next();
    });
});
```